# Unwrapping Optionals for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift2, option-type

I have the following code. I am using all Xcode suggestions possible plus various sources on SO etc. but I cannot seem to correct the optional issues:

```
var cell =
        tableview!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier as String) as? UITableViewCell?

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:identifier as String)
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
// ERROR HERE 
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("category_name") as! String
        // ERROR HERE

        var str = String(format: "%@%@%@",kServerURl,"/upload/",dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("category_image") as! String)

        cell?.imageView?.image =  UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:str)!)!)
// ERROR HERE

        return cell
//ERROR HERE
```

The error:

> VALUE OF OPTIONAL TYPE UITABLEVIEWCELL NOT UNWRAPPED DID YOU MEAN TO USE ! or ?

Not matter if i use ! or ? I get the same error, in some cases the error will resolve if two !! are added tier cell!!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is you've got a double optional going on here:

```
var cell =
    tableview!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier as String) as? UITableViewCell?
```

The `as?` says the cast could fail, so it wraps the value you're casting inside an optional. That value you're casting is *also* an optional (`String?`). So, if you look at the value of cell in the debugger, you see something like:

`Optional(Optional(<UITableViewCell:0x14f60bb10`

You can unwrap this explicitly by doing:

`cell!!` (two exclamations), but this is kinda dirty. Instead you only need one of the casts like so:

```
var cell =
    tableview!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier as String) as? UITableViewCell
```

Notice I removed the final question mark. Then you can just do:

```
cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

One final option is to just forcefully unwrap it in the first place with an exclamation like so:

```
tableview!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier as String) as! UITableViewCell
```

So then all you need is:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Answer (score 1):

The cell variable is an optional of type UITableViewCell?, so you have to unwrap it before you use it.  You should probably go read [the documentation on Optional Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) to familiarize yourself with their use.  Lines like:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

should be:

```
cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

or:

```
if let someCell = cell {
    someCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

You would use the first kind of unwrapping in the case where you know that the instance is not `nil`, like directly after your `nil` check if statement.  You would use the second kind of unwrapping if you don't know for sure it isn't `nil`.

Comment: HI, if add cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() I still get the same error. If I add (when prompted by Xcode) cell!!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() it works, is this possible - cell!!.back..

Comment: changed the initial assignment to this and its ok now : var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier as String) as UITableViewCell!;

Comment: can you remove the as UITableViewCell! part entirely?  The problem is that you're taking the result of that dequeue function, which is already a UITableViewCell? type, and then you're doing an optional cast (with as? UITableViewCell?) which makes you end up with a double optional type.